# Python - Transferring session between two browsers

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net, pyqt, qtwebkit

**The issue:**

I have written a ton of code (to automate some pretty laborious tasks online), and have used the mechanize library for `Python` to handle network requests. It is working very well, except now I have encountered a page which I **need** `javascript` functionality... mechanize does not handle `javascript`.

**Proposed Solution:**

I am using `PyQt` to write the GUI for this app, and it comes packaged with `QtWebKit`, which DOES handle `javascript`. I want to use `QtWebKit` to evaluate the `javascript` on the page that I am stuck on, and the easiest way of doing this would be to transfer my web session from mechanize over to `QtWebKit`.

I DO NOT want to use `PhantomJS`, `Selenium`, or `QtWebKit` for the entirety of my web requests; I 100% want to keep mechanize for this purpose. I'm wondering how I might be able to transfer my logged in session from mechanize to `QtWebKit`.

**Would this work?**

- Transfer all cookies from mechanize to `QtWebView`
- Transfer the values of all state variables (like `_VIEWSTATE`, etc.) from mechanize to `QWebView` (the page is an `ASP.net` page...)
- Change the User-Agent header of `QWebView` to be identical to mechanize...

I don't really see how I could make the two "browsers" appear more identical to the server... would this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered, I will post my work-around.

Basically, wanted to "transfer" my session from Mechanize (the python module) to the QtWebKits QWebView (PyQt4 module) because the vast majority of my project was automated headless, but I had encountered a road block where I had no choice but to have the user manually enter data into a possible resulting page (as the form was different each time depending on circumstances).

Instead of transferring sessions, **I met this requirement by utilizing QWebViews javascript functionality**. My method went like this:

1. Load page in Mechanize, and **save the downloaded HTML to a local temporary file**.
2. **Load this local file in QWebView**.
3. The **user can now enter required data into the local copy of this page**.
4. **Locate the form fields on this page, and pull the data the user entered using javascript**. You can do this by getting the main frame object for the page (**QWebView->Page()->MainFrame()**), and then evaluating javascript code to accomplish the above task (use **evaluateJavaScript()**).
5. Take the data you have extracted from the form fields, and use it to submit the form with the connection you still have open with mechanize.

That's it! A bit of a work-around, but it works none-the-less :\